# Is it possible to mock accessors by Mockito in Kotlin?

Tags: mockito, kotlin

Is it possible to mock getter and setter of the property by Mockito? Something like this:

```
@Test
fun three() {
    val m = mock<Ddd>() {
//        on { getQq() }.doReturn("mocked!")
    }
    assertEquals("mocked!", m.qq)
}
open class Ddd {
     var qq : String = "start"
        set(value) {
            field = value + " by setter"
        }
        get() {
            return field + " by getter"
        }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't find mocking setter useful if you mocking getter, so please provide an example.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To mock getter just write:

```
val m = mock<Ddd>()
`when`(m.qq).thenReturn("42")
```

also i suggest to use [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin), to use useful extensions and functions like `whenever`:

```
val m = mock<Ddd>()
whenever(m.qq).thenReturn("42")
```

Comment: what if `qq` is lateinit var

Comment: @RachitMishra enable mocking final methods, and you will be able to mock lateinit. See http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final

Comment: I am doing that, but still it is not working somewhat. I am using the latest mockito 2.0 +, is it that this won't work with powermock.

Comment: Please create new question for your problem. I can help you, but I need more details.

Answer (score 7):

Complementing IRus' answer, you could also use the following syntax:

```
val mockedObj = mock<SomeClass> {
  on { funA() } doReturn "valA"
  on { funB() } doReturn "valB"
}
```

or

```
val mockedObj = mock<SomeClass> {
  on(it.funA()).thenReturn("valA")
  on(it.funB()).thenReturn("valB")
}
```