# Set value for a non setter attribute in a mocked super class

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, mockito

I'm working on a mixed JVM project: Classes are mainly in Java and tests in Kotlin.

So I have a Java `MyClass` which extends a `ParentClass`. Both are Jakarta `@Entity`. They are separated since `ParentClass` can be used in other places:

```java
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class MyClass extends ParentClass {
  // some attributes
}
```

And `ParentClass` has attributes only with getter and no setters (is mandatory to not modify these values since the object is created):

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
public class ParentClass {
  private String value = "";
}
```

Now I'm testing some parts of the code and trying to mock this object to update value to a non null value.

Since there are no `setters`, the idea is to create mock to be able to modify the `getValue()` and return other value avoiding reflection.

I've tried to use something like `mock.when(myMock.getValue()).thenReturn("my string")` but it doesn't works.

In kotlin tests I've tried multiple lines:

```kotlin
val myMock = mock<MyClass>(CALLS_REAL_METHODS)

`when`(myMock.value).thenReturn("")
// or using mockito kotlin
whenever(myMock.value).thenReturn("")
```

First line is trying to force to call the real getter and then mock the getter in some of the next two lines and get desired value in that way.

But it seems that not work's in that way.

Also I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589038/13464279)

```kotlin
val myMock = mock<MyClass>()
// And also
val myMock = org.mockito.kotlin.mock<MyClass>()

// And these two
`when`(myMock.value).thenReturn("")
whenever(myMock.value).thenReturn("")
```

None of them works, I still have the "empty" object created for mockito with all values null/objects default.

Also tried:

```kotlin
val mock1: MyClass = mock(MyClass::class.java)
`when`(mock1.value).thenReturn("")
whenever(mock1.value).thenReturn("")

val mock2: MyClass = mock();
`when`(mock2.value).thenReturn("")
whenever(mock2.value).thenReturn("")

val mock3: MyClass = mock(CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
`when`(mock3.value).thenReturn("")
whenever(mock3.value).thenReturn("")
```

None of them works, my mock class has default values. But not other is that problem but also I want to modify the parent class which is not mocked.

So, what I'm missing? Is any inter-op problem using Java and Kotlin? Is some `@Entity` or `@MappedSuperclass` weird thing?

Do I will need to use reflection?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a spy, not a mock.

```kt
val mySpy = spy(MyClass())
println(mySpy.value)  // original value
`when`(mySpy.value).thenReturn("stubbedValue")
println(mySpy.value)  // stubbed value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works and I can avoid reflection, so I prefer this way.

Comment: BTW, your requirements are a bit strange - if the value is constant, never set in constructor or via a setter, what is the point of changing this constant in tests? JPA entities are normally easy to create - and mocking them is unusual

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer by Lesiak is great and I prefer that for avoiding to use reflection, but in case someone needs or want reflection, this is the workaround I did until I hit `spy()` method:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils

// ...

val myClass = MyClass()
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myClass , "value", "whatever")
```